# Spherical integration of vector function $\frac{\vec{r}\times(\vec{\mathbb{e}_z}\times\vec{r})}{r^3} \exp^{-2 r}\mathrm{d}{\vec{r}}$

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, vector-fields

In the context of a problem about the magnetic response of the electron cloud in the hydrogen atom I need the solution of the following volume integral of a vector function:

\begin{align} I &= \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\vec{r}\times(\vec{\mathbb{e}_z}\times\vec{r})}{r^3} \exp^{-2 r}\mathrm{d}{\vec{r}} \\ &= \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \begin{pmatrix}-xz \\ -yz \\ x^2+y^2 \end{pmatrix} \frac{\exp^{-2 r}}{r^3}\mathrm{d}{x}\mathrm{d}{y}\mathrm{d}{z}\end{align}

with $\vec{r}=\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix},\;\vec{\mathbb{e}}_z=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},\; r=|\vec{r}|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}.$

I have tried solving it with Mathematica, but it seems to evaluate for ever. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If I were doing it, I would immediately express it in (x,y,z) coordinates and get a 3-d integral in dxdydz.  Alternatively in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Well I did that and it looked not much nicer but I can add that of course!

Comment: Have you tried spherical coordinates?

Comment: Well that would have been my first Idea, but I am a bit lost how to deal with the vector terms then.

Comment: As @herb steinberg mentioned, you should use spherical coordinates. $\vec F= \frac{\vec{r}\times(\vec{\mathbb{e}_z}\times\vec{r})}{r^3} \exp^{-2 r}=(F_x,F_y,F_z)$. You should integrate every coordinate of this vector separately, switching to spherical system. For example, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}F_x(x,y,z)dxdydz=\int_0^\infty r^2 dr\int_0^\pi \sin(\theta) d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \,F_x(r,\theta,\phi)$, where $F_x=-xz\frac{e^{-2r}}{r^3}=-r\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta) \,r\cos(\theta)\frac{e^{-2r}}{r^3}$, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I can solve it now. I'll post the result then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry the $x$ and the $y$ component is $= 0$. For the $z$ component we obtain

\begin{align}
 I_z & = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} (r^2-z^2) \frac{\exp^{-2r}}{r}   \sin{(\vartheta)}    dr d\vartheta  d\varphi \\
& = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_0^\infty r \exp^{-2r} dr\int_0^\pi \sin^3(\vartheta)d\vartheta \int_0^{2\pi} d\varphi \\
& = \frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{1}{4} \frac{4}{3} 2\pi \\
& = \frac{1}{6}
\end{align}

Hence \begin{align}
 I & = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ \frac{1}{6}\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}